# Can enemies see an invisible Sombra being healed?

Tags: overwatch

If I heal my team's Sombra with:

- Mercy's Healing Beam,
- Zenyatta's Orb of Harmony
- Ana's Biotic Rifle

Will the animations that play for these three be seen by the enemy team? Namely:

- Will Mercy's healing beam be visible between the invisible Sombra and the Mercy?
- Will Zenyatta's Orb of Harmony show itself travelling to the invisible Sombra and then healing her?
- Will the dart splashes show when healing Sombra with the Biotic Rifle darts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Blizzard's forum](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20751545286#post-5) : Mercy's healing beam is only visible by Mercy.

For Ana and Zenyatta, particles are visible for the enemies to see. Meaning that you'll see Ana's dart impact on Sombra and you'll see Zenyatta's orb line reach Sombra (but not the orb itself)

Source : Tested it, wasn't the one to see it to record it... Sorry.